# Laravel 5.5 WhereIn query with null

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.5

```
return $places = Place::where('name', 'like', '%' . $request->name . '%')
            ->whereHas('eatCategories', function($q) use($kitchen){
                $q->WhereIn('eat_category_id', $kitchen);
            })
            ->whereHas('services', function($q) use($service){
                $q->WhereIn('service_id', $service);
            })
            ->whereHas('paymentMethods', function($q) use($payment){
                $q->WhereIn('place_attribute_id', $payment);
            })->get();
```

My query is working but if the variables are empty, the query is not working until all is full.

```
$q->WhereIn('eat_category_id', $kitchen);
```

If `$kitchen` is empty, how can I resume the query?

My route :

```
Route::get('/filter-places/{name?}/{kitchen?}/{service?}/{payment?}', 'SystemController@filterPlaces');
```

Comment: Why are you running a return on the query?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A simple `if` inside would do the trick I think:

```
 $places = Place::where('name', 'like', '%' . $request->name . '%');
 if($kitchen) {
     $places->whereHas('eatCategories', function($q) use($kitchen){
        $q->WhereIn('eat_category_id', $kitchen);
     })
 }
 if($service) {
     $places->whereHas('services', function($q) use($service){
        $q->WhereIn('service_id', $service);
     })
 }
 if($payment) {
     $places->whereHas('paymentMethods', function($q) use($payment){
        $q->WhereIn('place_attribute_id', $payment);
     })
 }
 return $places->get();
```